# When two gas molecules collide, can they send out an IR photon?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, photons, collision, gas

When a ball bounces on the ground, each bounce is smaller than the previous one because of friction in the system, i.e. the collision between the ball and the ground is not completely elastic. We are taught that the kinetic energy lost in an inelastic collision is turned into heat.

What about when two gas molecules collide in the air? Is their collision always elastic, or does part of their kinetic energy sometimes turn into heat? And if so, does this heat leave the collision in the form of an IR photon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is common for colliding molecules to emit IR and microwaves.

When molecules collide some of the kinetic energy may go into rotational and vibrational excitations, so that after the collision one or both of the molecules are in an excited state. Then the molecules decay by emitting a photon. Typically the decay of rotational excited states emits microwave photons and the decay of vibrationally excited states emits infra-red photons.

At room temperature the kinetic energy is usually too low to excite vibrational states, so the gas would emit only microwave radiation from the decay of the rotational modes. Typically you need to heat the gas to a few hundred degrees C to see much infra-red emission.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But a follow-up qn: Surely only a certain type of gases, namely the so-called greenhouse gases, can emit IR photons? So that wouldn't apply to e.g. the nitrogen in the air? But perhaps the nitrogen can emit microwaves, as you mentioned? And could you maybe point me to a source where I could read more about this? 

Comment: Oh yeah... And does your answer mean that no photon is emitted in the collision itself, but the collision causes an excitation of the molecules which later causes the emission of a photon?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård As a first approximation the molecules have to have an electric dipole moment to radiate photons, and that's true for both rotational and vibrational transitions. So homogenous diatomics like N₂ and O₂ would not radiate as their dipole moment is zero. You mention CO₂, and that can undergo vibrational transitions because a dipole moment is created as the molecule bends. There will be a non-zero probability to radiate a photon during the collision but I don't know how large that probability is. I would guess most photons are radiated after the collision.

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård  Just to be clear about the main problem with CO2/CH4 ... they are transparent to visible light .. all the energy in the visible spectrum hits the ground/water and warms it during the day .....  all that visible energy is turned into IR energy (photons) by the ground/water and these photons can not escape as easily because increased CO2/CH4 which absorbs IR.

Comment: Is that the black-body radiation of the gas, or a separate phenomenon?

Comment: @OrangeDog gases do not black body radiate. BBR needs a high electron density and gases simply don't have enough electrons per cubic metre. The gases will be radiating at specific frequencies instead of a continuous BBR spectrum.

Comment: Wow, thank you again, this is really useful information all around!  My main reason for asking was a discussion of whether gases like the nitrogen in the atmosphere can somehow contribute to the temperature of Earth, and I felt it can't, because it can't radiate. Now, @JohnRennie seems to confirm that. Also great to know that gases do not do BBR. The only thing I'm missing now is a firm source to back this up...  Anybody who has that? Not that I don't trust you, but just for the sake of spreading the knowledge.

Comment: @PhysicsDave, I think you're being a little bit unfair to the greenhouse gases! Without them, the Earth would be about 32 degrees colder, so they say, and so it likely wouldn't harbor any life. 

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Yes its all a delicate balancing act ....!

Comment: @PhysicsDave, life is indeed a fragile and mysterious thing. 

Comment: Here's one from my 12 year-old son: "If there's no friction anywhere in the system, and I slap someone in the face, will it hurt?"

Comment: @JohnRennie, here's a follow-up qn for you: If there is a gas cloud of H2 out in the universe, held together by its own gravity and far away from any solid bodies, will it maintain its temperature forever? Because it can't radiate, and there's nothing it can collide with, other than itself!... Or will it eventually find a way to radiate out all its energy, after all? Because of the non-zero chance of emitting a photon in a collision or through some other mechanism?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård I'm pretty sure there is always a chance of a molecule exceeding escape velocity via collisions and leaving. So the cloud is going to cool down, and the hotter it is the faster it will cool.

Comment: @OrangeDog, true... But that's more of the cloud being depleted than the cloud cooling down.  So if we disregard the possibility of a molecule escaping, can it still cool down? Or will it now maintain its temperature forever...

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård the particles with the highest energy are leaving, reducing the average energy of the cloud, causing a reduction in the cloud's temperature. If you discard all the ways that the temperature will decrease, then indeed the temperature will not decrease.

Comment: @OrangeDog, I get that the molecules with the highest energy leave, thus leaving the remaining gas cooler. That's the same way boiling works, and why there is such a thing as a "boiling point".  However, I'm really interested to know if this is the ONLY way for the gas could to cool down...? Because then, if we still count the escaped molecules as part of the cloud (only in a long-distance relationship, so to speak), then indeed, it hasn't cooled down.