# What is the temperature of a greenhouse gas?

Tags: temperature, thermal-radiation, atmospheric-science, gas, infrared-radiation

The temperature of a gas is usually the sum of the kinetic energy of its particles, right?

Whereas the temperature of a solid object is given by the Stefan-Bolzmann equation, as a function of how much thermal radiation it emits:

$$j^* = σT^4$$ (from Wikipedia, Stefan-Bolzmann equation)

But when you expose a greenhouse gas such as CO2 to infrared (IR) radiation, which is a form of thermal radiation, it too starts emitting IR radiation in all directions. If the IR exposure stops, the gas too very soon stops emitting IR, within a femtosecond or so, and the IR energy absorbed by the gas as excited vibrations is not normally converted into kinetic energy, as I've understood. (Even though it COULD possibly be converted into kinetic energy during a collision with another molecule, but this is unusual, right?) But still, for as long as the gas is exposed to IR radiation, it can exert both kinetic energy and IR energy on its surrounding.

So what is the temperature of the greenhouse gas? Is it still just the kinetic energy, as for other gases, or is it the kinetic energy plus the IR energy? Or does it have two separate types of temperature, one for kinetics and one for IR, and they can't be combined?

Comment: No, it's wrong.

Comment: Are you assuming that only greenhouse gases emit thermal radiation and other gases don't?

Comment: Hi Karolina. Polyatomic molecules like CO₂ have rotational and vibrational energy, not just kinetic energy. When CO₂ absorbs IR light that energy is stored as vibrational energy. When you're working out the temperature of the gas you have to include the rotational and vibrational energy in your calculations.

Comment: Gas does radiate all the time, not only when exposed to IR. At the same time it absorbs radiation from other sources, so the net effect may seem like no radiation in some cases.

Comment: @JohnRennie I think the question could be rephrased as "are the vibrational-rotational modes of a population of GHG molecules in good thermal contact with the translational-motion modes of the same population of molecules?".  My guess would be that intermolecular collisions are crucial to heat transfer between the vibrational-rotational modes and the translational modes, and that the answer therefore depends on the density of the gas, but I don't have enough evidence for this to make it an answer.

Comment: @toxicPsychotic (lovely name!) yes, I am assuming that only greenhouse gases, i.e. gases with a dipole moment, can radiate. This is in accordance with the discussion in this thread: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742784/when-two-gas-molecules-collide-can-they-send-out-an-ir-photon Is it not correct?

Comment: @JohnRennie, so you are saying that the vibrational energy of the molecules' excited state contributes to the gas' temperature? So while it vibrates, it is warmer. That wasn't exactly what I asked, though... The temperature of a body can be calculated from how much thermal radiation it EMITS, according to the Stefan-Bolzmann law... So the qn was actually whether the photons EMITTED by the gas when the excited state decays add to their temperature...?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård the Stefan-Boltzmann law is not applicable to gases. The temperature of a gas is not simply related to how much IR it radiates. There is a relationship between temperature and radiation for a gas but it is different for every gas as it depends on the emission spectrum. Many gases like O₂ and N₂ barely radiate at all in the IR. In this respect the (few) greenhouse gases are unusual.

Comment: @DanielHatton, your question is interesting, too!  But I believe John Rennie already answered that qn "no, not at atmospheric temperatures" earlier today, in the link I posted to toxicPsychotic just now. At least, he said that collisions at those temperatures rarely cause enough excitement to create an IR photon. I assumed, perhaps wrongly, that IR photons rarely turn into kinetic energy at those temperatures. Too few collisions, I suppose.

Comment: @JohnRennie, so there IS a relationship still (between the emitted radiation of a gas and its temperature)? And N2 and O2 DO radiate some IR?!...  How do they do that??